# RxJS - using windowWhen() for maxWait and maxElements windows

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to bundle calls to a server to a maximum of maxEntries, but don't want to wait longer than maxWait ms. This used to be available as `windowWithTimeOrCount()` in RxJS 4, but was removed from RxJS 5.

Everything is working great, except that the last element of a window is lost. And speaking of 'lost' - that is how I feel now. Any RxJS Guru out there who could tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
 private chunk(queue: Observable<CacheEntry>, maxEntries: number, maxWait: number): Observable<Observable<CacheEntry>> {

    // We have an incoming stream of CacheEntries to be retrieved. We want to bundle these in units of max maxEntries
    // but wait no longer than max maxWait ms. We return an Observable, that emits Observables of CacheEntries that
    // complete after maxEntries / maxWait (whatever comes first).
    const toggleSubject = new Subject<void>();

    return queue

    // Start emitting a new Observable every time toggleSubject emits.
    // (bufferWhen() wouldn't work as we have to count the elements as they come and buffer only gives us the
    // complete collection)
      .windowWhen(() => toggleSubject)

      // map() is called once for every window (maxEntries/maxWait)
      // the inner do() is called for every element in the window, allowing us to set up the timeout callback and to
      // count all elements, then emitting on toggleSubject, triggering a new Observable.
      // (We have to map() here - instead of an outer do() -  because otherwise the original obs would be streamed
      // and the hooked up version with the inner do() would never be called.)
      .map((obs) => {
        // counts the number of cacheEntries already in this stream
        let count = 0;
        // flag to kill the timeout callback
        let done = false;
        // we have to return an Observable
        return obs.do(() => {
            count++;
            if (count === 1) {
              // we start counting when the first element is streamed.
              IntervalObservable.create(maxWait).first().subscribe(() => {
                if (!done) {
                  //trigger due to maxWait
                  toggleSubject.next(null);
                }
              });
            }
            if (count > (maxEntries)) {
              done = true;
              // trigger due due to maxEntries(' + maxEntries + ')');
              toggleSubject.next(null);
            }
          }
        );
      });
  }
```

The element that triggers `toggleSubject.next(null)` due to `if (count > (maxEntries))` is lost (not in any window).

EDIT: maxTime starts ticking the moment the first element of a new Observable is pushed. `if (count === 1 )`. This is a) the reason I'm working from inside of the windowed Observables in `map()` and b) important because that is the required behavior.

Example: maxElements: 100, maxWait: 100. 101 Elements are pushed at t=99. Expected behavior: At t=99 an Observable with 100 Elements is pushed. 1 Element is left over. Counter + Timer reset. At t=199 the counter for the second 'chunk' expires and pushes an Observable with 1 element.

(In this example Brandons (see answer) code would - if I read it correctly - push an Observable at t=99 with 100 elements and **one ms later**, at t=100, an Observable with one element.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you don't want to use `map` for side effects like this.  As you noticed, you end up dropping items.

Here's a generic method that I think will do what you want.

Note: RXJS 5 currently has an [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1905) with the type definition for this overload of publish.  I've added some typecasts that should allow it to compile in TypeScript.

```
chunk<T>(queue: Observable<T>, maxEntries: number, maxWait: number): Observable<Observable<T>> {
    // use publish() so that we can subscribe multiple times to the same stream of data.
    return queue.publish(entries => {
        // observable which will trigger after maxWait
        const timer = IntervalObservable.create(maxWait);
        // observable which will trigger after maxEntries
        const limit = entries.take(maxEntries).last();
        // observable which will trigger on either condition
        const endOfWindow = limit.takeUntil(timer);

        // use endOfWindow to close each window.
        return entries.windowWhen(() => endOfWindow) as Observable<T>;
    }) as Observable<Observable<T>>;
}
```

Edit:

If you don't want the timer to start until after the first item arrives in each window, then you can do it like so:

```
chunk<T>(queue: Observable<T>, maxEntries: number, maxWait: number): Observable<Observable<T>> {
    // use publish() so that we can subscribe multiple times to the same stream of data.
    return queue.publish(entries => {
        // observable which will trigger after maxWait after the first
        // item in this window arrives:
        const timer = entries.take(1).delay(maxWait);
        // observable which will trigger after maxEntries
        const limit = entries.take(maxEntries).last();
        // observable which will trigger on either condition
        const endOfWindow = limit.takeUntil(timer);

        // use endOfWindow to close each window.
        return entries.windowWhen(() => endOfWindow) as Observable<T>;
    }) as Observable<Observable<T>>;
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Looks good (and I myself stupid :-( ) I'll try this tomorrow. My approach was a bit more complicated...

Comment: Hmmm... looks good, but doesn't do the trick.

`publish()`returns Observable<T>, what is expected is Observable<Observable<T>>.

The way I read your code, timer triggers independently (every maxWait ms regardless of what happens on the stream). That's the reason I'm trying to get the feedback from inside of the 'windowWhen()' Observable - I start counting when the first elements arrives. (See op edit.)

Comment: This overload of publish is `publish(func: (Observable<T>) => Observable<U>): Observable<U>`.  In otherwords, publish() returns whatever type of observable the factory method you supply returns.  In this case, I am returning an Observable<Observable<T>>.

Comment: Are you sure about that? From the RxJS publish.d.ts file:

`export declare function publish<T>(selector?: (source: Observable<T>) => Observable<T>): Observable<T> | ConnectableObservable<T>;`

Comment: Ah they've changed the signature in RxJS5, but not the actual functionality.  Here's the signature from RXJS4: `publish<TResult>(selector: (source: ConnectableObservable<T>) => Observable<TResult>): Observable<TResult>;`.  I think if you cast it, it will work, but I'll open a GH Issue to check.

Comment: actually issue was opened last week: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1905

Comment: Your solution looks a lot better than mine and I really would like to use it and yes, your comment on the complexities of writing stuff like this is totally correct. But I haven't even really understood how your solution is supposed to work. `entries` is a continuous, never ending stream of elements. When, where and how do the triggers (`timer`, `limit`) reset? The way I read the code, this is a one shot solution.

Comment: `windowWhen` calls the factory method on every new window, so each time a window is triggered to close, the factory method gets called to create a new trigger.  The new trigger starts a new count and new timer that newly start watching the continuous stream of `entries` at the current location in the stream.  The key trick here is that `publish` gives us a multicast version of the queue that we can keep reusing.  See if this helps: http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/publish.html

Comment: Socrates: 'I know that I know nothing' :-) Thanks for your patience. I'll try it as soon as RxJS pushes the new signatures as npm.

Comment: I added some typecasts to the example that *should* let it compile.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've come up with is toggling `windowWhen()`on the async scheduler.

```
if (count === (maxEntries)) {
  done = true;
  this.LOGGER.debug(' - trigger due due to maxEntries(' + maxEntries + ')');
  Rx.Scheduler.async.schedule(()=>toggleSubject.next(null));
}
```

The problem was that `windowWhen()` completed the returned Observables immediately - preventing any downstream operators from receiving that last value.

Sorry for asking (and answering) the question. I tried `Rx.Scheduler.async` etc. before posting here, but somehow it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Note that your windows may end up with more than `maxEntries` entries if the items are being pushed into the observable synchronously since they will all get pushed through the current window before your async call executes.  The complexities involved in writing operations like this is one of the reasons the general advice is to *not* use Subjects and instead build your operator out of existing operators.